# r raster: unique returns duplicated values?

Tags: raster, r

I am using function `unique()` in package `raster`. I expect it to return the unique values for each layer, yet I get duplicated values... is that the expected result, or is there an issue somewhere?

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*10)
s <- stack(r, as.integer(round(r/2)))

unique(s)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 0 0 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unique()` returns the **unique combinations** of rows for all layers, similarly as the R base function `unique()` does on a data-frame.

If you want the unique values for each rows, separately, you could just use `lapply()` on the `unstack()` object:

```
lapply(unstack(s), unique)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Matifou already explained why he got the answer he got. Here are two alternative approaches (very similar)

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- round(runif(ncell(r))*10)
unique(r)
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Unique values for a multi-layer object

```
s <- stack(r, round(r/2), round(r/3))
u <- unique(s)
```

Unique combinations

```
do.call(rbind, u)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
#[1,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9    10
#[2,]    0    0    1    2    2    2    3    4    4     4     5
#[3,]    0    0    1    1    1    2    2    2    3     3     3
```

Unique by layer

```
lapply(u, unique)
#[[1]]
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
#[[2]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
# 
#[[3]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3
```

or

```
lapply(1:nlayers(s), function(i) unique(s[[i]]))
#[[1]]
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0 1 2 3
```